# Unable to create file in externalFileDirectory using download manger in Blackberry OS android

Tags: android, download-manager, blackberry-android

I am unable to create file in externalFilesDir using below mathod in blackberry OS android.

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, "Update", "File.apk");
```

When i checked the folder than folder doesn't have read/write permission in Blackberry passport.

/Android/data/com.xy.yz/files/Update this should be created but when i saw the folder is has only /Android/data/com.xy.yz and m not able to create any file or folder inside that

Comment: You should first create the 'Update' folder before you try to let somebody put a file in it.

Comment: Did you request permissions to write to external storage?

Comment: I have added the permission.

Comment: Please answer all my questions.

Comment: Sorry, What is saw folder was create in external storage but folder doesn't have any permission to write any thing in that

Comment: And  I have also tried with folder creation before setting the path for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix the issue. I don't know what is issue but when i trying to download inside the folder its give me file read/write permission issue.

But if i want to download in root directory like downloads then i will not giving me any error.

I have the code of path to download

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "xyz.apk");
```